# Выборка полей без повторения в MYSQL

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Есть ли такая возможность в mysql, сделать выборку по полям так, чтобы он не брал повторяющиеся поля? Примерно так:
id    index    user
1       25      2
3       25      2
То есть, взять только первую строку, так index повторяется. Если что-то не понятно, уточняйте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `user` GROUP BY `index`
```

Comment: Mysql. Нормальный sql обматерил бы.